# org.hibernate.TransientObjectException if any many-to-one fields are null (or not selected in form)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, playframework

I am using jpa with play framework.I have an entity JobseekerDetails

```
@Entity
public class JobseekerDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "jobseekerDetails_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long jobseekerDetails_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "basicEducation_id")
    private JobseekerFormBasicEducation basicEducation;

     @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "masterEducation_id")
    private JobseekerFormMasterEducation masterEducation;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctrateEducation_id")
    private JobseekerFormDoctrateEducation doctrateEducation;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> certificateName =new ArrayList<String>();

    @Column(length = 3000)
    private String resume;

    private Long experience;

    private String skills;

    private String resumePath;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "industry_id")
    private JobseekerFormIndustry industry;

     @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "functionalArea_id")
    private JobseekerFormFunctionalArea functionalArea;

}
```

which have a many-to-one relation with other entities like **JobseekerFormFunctionalArea** , **JobseekerFormIndustry** etc.These entities have fixed value which is already saved in the database.

When JobseekerDetails is saved all its details should be saved with corresponding manytoone relation ids but donot save to Entity  JobseekerFormFunctionalArea and JobseekerFormIndustry as they are predefined

My problem is that when i save(through my form) all the manytoone relation fields ids in JobseekerDetails it is saved properly but when submit my form without selecting any value in any manytoone relation fields For ex if i dont select anything in my fuctionalArea_id field it gives the below exception

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException:object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

If I select all the fields the details are saved but if I dint select anyone field which is mapped manytoone in my model then it gives above exception

**But jpa automatically set nullable=true then why this happend**

I have searched a bit and found that this problem can be solved by adding cascade .I added **cacade type Merge** but getting the above same exception.

I also tryed setting nullable=true but getting same error

On setting **cascade = CascadeType.ALL** and **cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST** I am getting below exception

```
PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't select any 'basicEducation' in the form and you are saving form then there is new object there with empty id. So you have:

```
jobseekerDetails.basicEducation = new JobseekerFormBasicEducation ()
```

This causes `TransientObjectException`

To avoid it you have to set

```
jobseekerDetails.basicEducation=null
```

before saving.

Comment: see my edits above getting exception on adding cascade type all, and also cascade type all(as I know) would try to save data in my corresponding manytoone mapped table and I dont want this as described in my quetion.Correct me if I am wrong